# Sending data from one activity to another startactivityforresult

Tags: android

I searched on the forums but couldn't find the right answer for me.
I've included the relevant parts below

ACTIVITY ONE

```
implicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            // Call startImplicitActivation() when pressed
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this,
                ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
```

and a little lower

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");


            String input=data.getStringExtra(TAG);
            mUserTextView.setText(input);
        }
```

This is activity 2 after user enters some data

```
String input=mEditText.getText().toString();


    Intent i = new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("TAG",input);
    startActivity(i);       
    this.setResult(RESULT_OK);      
    finish();
```

No error messages at all but the text on screen doesnt update. it is supposed to

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class);` no need for this. use `Intent i = getIntent()` and make sure the keys match

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: dont startActivity hust setResult(RESULT_OK,i) and finish()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't need start activity in second class:

you need change your code with:

```
Intent i = new Intent();  // or // Intent i = getIntent()
i.putExtra("TAG",input);
setResult(RESULT_OK , i);         
finish();
```

and for cancel that,

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, i);        
finish();
```

Comment: why `new Intent()` `getItent()` does the job

Comment: can we send data to the 2nd activity when we start it with start startActivityForResult ? I mean a two way data transfer ?

Comment: Yes you can, use `putExtra` method on intent object when you want start it.

Answer (score 3):

On your Activity2 you are launching a new instance of ExplicityLoadedActivity instead of returning into the previous instance.

You should only set the result, and finish your second activity.

Here's the code you can try on your 2nd activity:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("TAG",input);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);        
finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
String input=data.getStringExtra("TAG");
```

in place of

```
 String input=data.getStringExtra(TAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to set result code in `ExplicitlyLoadedActivity`

```
String input=mEditText.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("TAG",input);
this.setResult(RESULT_OK,i);      
finish();
```

and in `ActivityLoaderActivity` access that result string i.e.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");


            String input=data.getStringExtra("TAG");
            mUserTextView.setText(input);
        }
```